# Vue.js Snotify - Triggers multiple calls in async

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await, axios

The following is the code I use to invoke a remote call using axios and based on the error type from the server error or success notification is shown to the user. Here is a [link](https://artemsky.github.io/vue-snotify/documentation/essentials/examples.html) to the original doc.

```
async getResponseFromServer() {
  if (this.errors.all().length == 0) {
    this.$snotify.clear();

    this.$snotify.async(
      "Getting Data",
      "Loading...",

      () =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          return this.getDataCommonResponse()
            .then(function(response) {
              if (response.status && response.type == undefined) {
                resolve({
                  title: response.error,
                  body: "This is the balance",
                  config: {
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    position: SnotifyPosition.centerTop
                  }
                });
              } else {
                reject({
                  title: "Error",
                  body: response.error,
                  config: {
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    position: SnotifyPosition.centerTop
                  }
                });
              }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {});
        })
    );
  }
}
```

In the GitHub also there is an [open issue](https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify/issues/54). It says Snotify will make 2 API calls but multiple requests are made. Is there a way to limit to a single API call?

Is there a way to fix this?